# Can you have types that refer to each other in Julia?

Tags: julia

I get `ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: Expression not defined` for the following code:

```
struct IntLiteral
    value::Int
end

struct Plus
    left::Expression
    right::Expression
end

struct Minus
    left::Expression
    right::Expression
end

const Expression = Union{IntLiteral, Plus, Minus}
```

If I declare `Expression` ahead of `Plus` and `Minus`, I get a similar error. Wrapping the code in a `module` doesn't change anything, either.

Is there a way to reference a type ahead of its declaration in Julia? If not, what is the recommended solution for cases like this, where two types depend on each other? Just remove the type annotations?

In this particular case, I believe I could make `Expression` an abstract type, and have the others be subtypes of it. Is that recommended in this case? What about the general case?

Comment: Perhaps `Expression` should be defined as an abstract type, see the docs at https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/types/#Abstract-Types-1

Comment: " I believe I could make Expression an abstract type, and have the others be subtypes of it. Is that recommended in this case?" Yes. "What about the general case?" Traits and type parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently, no.  See [issue #269](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/269) for more details.